# Difference between these two examples?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between this:

```
var test = function(callback) {
    callback(4);
    return;
};

test(function(x) { alert(x); });
```

And this (notice that the callback call is actually returned):

```
var test = function(callback) {
    return callback(4);
};

test(function(x) { alert(x); });
```

Comment: Not in this case since the callback doesn't return a value. But if it did, you would see a difference.

Comment: if you run it you should be able to tell... the first code does not actually return value

Comment: When you call `test()` you ignore its return value.

Comment: Yes, there's a difference. No, the way you're using `test` it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one always returns `undefined` when invoked. The second one returns whatever `callback(4)` returns. Incidentally, in your example that's also `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your quick responses. This makes a lot of sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

They both return `undefined`, so no there is no difference. But the second one returns undefined, because the callback returns undefined. The first one just returns undefined without exception.

For example:

```
var y = test(function(x){ return x*2; });
```

In your first variation `y` gets assigned the value `undefined`. In the second it gets the value `8` (The return value of `callback(4)`.

Answer (score 1):

the first example executes the callback function and returns `undefined`.

the second function returns the value *returned by the callback function*;